# Prove $\sum_{i=0}^n \prod_{j=0,\ i\neq j}^n \frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}=1$

Tags: summation, products

Let
$$
l_i(x)=\prod_{j=0,\ i\neq j}^n \frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}
$$
where $x_0,...x_n\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall_{i,j}\ i\neq j \implies x_i\neq x_j$

Show that:
$$
\forall_{x\in \mathbb {R}}\ \sum_{i=0}^n l_i(x)=1
$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm confused on where should I start. Should I try induction?

Comment: Eventually perhaps, but I would say that in this case it's best to start with small examples ($n=1,2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to note that the polynomial $p(x) = \left(\sum_{i=0}^n l_i(x)\right) - 1$ has degree at most $n$, but the equation $p(x) = 0$ has at least $n+1$ solutions at $x = x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually to prove that you can use the fact that :

Given 2 polynoms $P,Q$ of degree $n$:

$$ P=Q $$ if and only if
 $$ \exists(x_1,...,x_{n+1})\in R^{n+1}, \forall i \in [1,n+1], P(x_i)=Q(x_i) $$

So here you have to show that the polynom $ \sum l_i $ is equal to the polynom constant to $1$.

For this, evaluate $\sum_i l_i$ in each $x_i$ (hopefully you have (n+1) values: the $x_i$ ... and conclude.

Comment: This is equivalent to the answer Omnomnomnom already posted.

Comment: Actually yes, We were writting at the same time.